# How can i make Jaws V17 to read the contents of Mathjax formula

Tags: javascript, accessibility, mathjax, jaws-screen-reader

[image]

In the aboveimage, the JAWS reader can't read the formula which was generated by Mathjax. It reads as negative ab = negative 11(eleven) = negative(0.1)

Jaws isn't able to read the over such as (a/b) or (a by b). It can't read the powers like (x - h)power2 is read as ("x h two"), skips all the math punctuations.

Can anyone help on this kind of problem?